# Chromium OS Cloudready install without wiping storage

Tags: 64-bit, chromium

I installed cloudready "Chromium OS" on a blank PC, I did the 32 bit version of cloudready even though the PC is 64bit for some reason. I used it for a while and it worked ok, except for netflix "streaming driver". Now I want to upgrade/migrate into cloudready version 64bit. This involves same process as before, install from USB wipe out disk, done.

Is there a way to install chromium OS, either same version or different  but without having to wipe out the disk, maintain the storage "download folder" in chromium?

Comment: If you need to have 64-bit instead of 32 then you'll have to reinstall.

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to prevent the install from wiping the storage drive/folder in chromium. Or does the install always format the partition even if I'm only going from chromium OS to Chromium OS. I already installed 64 bit before, I would like to know if I can keep my local files when I do a clean install again.

Comment: If the files are important you should have a backup. I'm not familiar with the installation process of this OS so I won't speculate about what may happen. But if I was the one doing it I would always assume and prepare for the worst case scenario.

Comment: I'd definitely do a backup anyways, but since I have some large virtual box files I'd rather avoid the time loss and effort of re-download or usb transfer